# Algorithmically fracture a mesh in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, 3d-meshes, mesh, dynamic-mesh

I want to create a plugin which **shatters/fractures meshes**, so I can make every object **destructible** if I want to. Like in **Unreal's built-in feature**.

My quick approach to this problem is **randomly generating cuts (planes)**:

- every cut **divides the mesh** into **2 groups**: **left** side of the cut and **right** side of the cut,
- at the points where it **intersects** the mesh, I **add vertices to both groups.**
- and add **1-1 face** to each group with these **new vertices**.
- **create the new mesh**.

Is there a better way? What do you recommend? Is my way even possible? If yes, what API methods should I use?

Comment: Look for Voronoi shattering or fracturing

Comment: Your proposal sounds reasonable. How far have you gotten in implementing it using the [Mesh class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)? Have you gotten stuck with your implementation anywhere we can help with, or identified a problem with your method that you'd like to find an alternative solution to fix? We need a specific goal to give you good answers — in what way should the proposed answers be "better" than what you've described?